# Android FragmentPagerAdapter and cursor loaders

Tags: android, cursor, loader, fragmentpageradapter

i'm trying to implement a custom cursor loader which loads data from my db into fragments hosted in a fragmentpageradapter.
i have an Activity (extends SherlockFragmentActivity) which has a Fragment which this implements a fragmentpageradapter (via the new nested fragments).
each fragment under the fragmentpageradapter implements a custom cursor loader that generates data to display. i initiate the loader in onActivityCreated and restart it on onResume and destroy it on onDestroy. lets say i am in page 1, the pager automatically initiate also page 2 (default behavior for a more fluid transaction) the problem is if i add an item to be displayed in page 2 (from the actionbar) and i am in page 1, when i swipe to page to the loader wont refresh the data.

any thoughts ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to stop the loader as the LoaderManager and FragmentManager work together to handle that for you.  That being said, I'm not sure that it's the cause of your problem.  Over the last month I have found numerous bugs with the loaders.  Although, most of those are related to the loaders not updating.

I know there is an existing bug with loaders but I don't have time to track it down.  Here is the suggested work-around for that.  Give this a try.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Start or restart the loader.  Note: this is a work-around to an Android
    // bug with loaders where they are not always properly activated with life-cycle
    // changes in the activity/fragment.
    Loader<Object> loader = getLoaderManager().getLoader((int) mId);
    if (loader != null && ! loader.isReset()) {
        mStatusLoader = (StatusItemLoader) getLoaderManager().restartLoader(
                                                    (int) mId, null, mLoadListener);
    } else {
        mStatusLoader = (StatusItemLoader) getLoaderManager().initLoader(
                                                    (int) mId, null, mLoadListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this but still it doesn't work, i think the problem is the life cycle of a fragment inside a fragmentpageradapter...